# Translating dimensions in SQL reporting DB to Sitecore

Tags: experience-analytics

I am on a task where I am trying to validate reporting db data against xConnect shard data. I have the shard SQL sorted out, but I am havign a hard time trying to understand the reporting DB. I know where dimensions are in Sitecore, but I am trying to figure out where DimensionKeyId and SegmentId roll up to.

[image]